# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method acquireEnvironmentalHdrCubeMap()

Tags: java, android, flutter, kotlin, augmented-reality

I have this `No virtual method` error when using `ArCore` via flutter plugin [arcore_flutter_plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/)

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method acquireEnvironmentalHdrCubeMap()[Lcom/google/ar/core/ArImage; in class Lcom/google/ar/core/LightEstimate; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.ar.core.LightEstimate' appears in /data/app/~~ICg-b27T7FDh1Fo0i1vyuQ==/com.example.arcore_test-Lsft1_3lhOxQyuP98Q0oTA==/base.apk)
```

This function's article is [here](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/com/google/ar/core/LightEstimate) , I guess this function is supposed is belonging to `com.google.ar:core`, however cant be called somehow?

I am using `1.37.0` and change this to `1.33.0`, but in vain.

in AndroidManifest.xml

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.google.ar:core:1.37.0'
```

What this error means? , how can I solves?